# Проблема с заданием шрифта в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, шрифты

```
    public class RecordList extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<Integer> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.records);

        // создаем адаптер
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
                R.layout.list_text, TimeRecord) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                textView.setTypeface(typeface);
                return viewGroup;
            }
        };


        //подключаем адаптер
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Разметка к этому классу records.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/touchpadon"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка для элемента списка . list_text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Ругается на строчку `TextView textView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.text1);`
Говорит что требуется TextView , а мой text1 - это widget.View ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно явное приведение к типу виджета на разметке (здесь `TextView`), так как метод `findViewById()` сам не в состоянии определить, какого именно из наследников `View` он нашел на этой разметке:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
   text.setTypeface(typeface);
return convertView;
```

В вашем случае, кстати, можно вообще обойтись без поиска виджета в XML дереве, так как он там один и использовать прямое привидение (для экономии ресурса устройства):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   ((TextView)convertView).setTypeface(typeface);
return convertView;
```

Так же вы пытались привести виджет `TextView` к классу `ViewGroup`, но он является наследником класса `View` и "ругается" соответственно, так как такое приведение не возможно.

Comment: ругается android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup. Невозможно говорит это приведение осуществить. А тут у человека в ответе вообще без приведения http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread805856.html   . Ну может конечно они изменили код..

Comment: Поменял везде ViewGroup на View , кроме параметров метода public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) . Вроде всё работает. Но почему ViewGroup не работал не понял

Comment: Я не понимаю разницы. Я вообще не знаю еще ничего о методах адаптера и не правильно будет сейчас это начать изучать. Мне по окончанию программки надо в основы вернуться. Использовав ваш код я в списке вместо всех значений которые хранятся в списке TimeRecord  получил надпись TEXTVIEW

Comment: А тот код который у меня был, работает исправно, чем он плох?

Comment: Да, я в очередной раз смотрю мимо, моя вина, что ввел вас в заблуждение, вы обращались не к паренту родителя, а создали свой объект. Вам нужно было просто получать из родителя не `ViewGroup`, а `View` (так как возвращаемое значение - виджет `TextView`, а он не относится к контейнерому типу и не является его наследником). Исправил в очередной раз, теперь, думаю правильно.

Comment: да, всё работает. А чем хуже вместо  convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);   написать View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); ?

Comment: @Turalllb В общем то нет никакой особой разницы, выгода в том, что создается меньше объектов и меньше нагрузка на сборщик мусора.